# How to keep two For Each loops at the same level

Tags: vb.net

I have a for each for every products qty in a an array I also want to pass a for each for every products id in an array at the same time. i want both id and qty to be inserted into a table at the same time, same level... I cant get nesting to do this, help???

```
Dim strSQLCommand As String
For Each productQtys In productQty
    For Each productIds In productId
        strSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO Orders(SessionID, productID, qty, orderDate) " & _
            "Values ('" & strSessionID & "','" & productIds & "','" & productQtys & "','" & dateOfOrder & "');"
        Dim objOleDbConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        objOleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabaseNameAndLocation)
        objOleDbConnection.Open()
        Dim objOleDbCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        objOleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQLCommand, objOleDbConnection)
        objOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objOleDbConnection.Close()
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Why do you need to iterate both the quantity and the ID? Wouldn't you just iterate by the ID, and then do whatever you want with the quantity per-product?

Comment: i want both id and qty to be inserted into a table at the same time, same level... I cant get nesting to do this, help???

Comment: Because I want to iterate through each id and each qty of a particular item, both which are in arrays.

Comment: Could you please explain more carefully what outcome you want, and what you are attempting in order to achieve it; as your question stands it is quite incomprehensible.

Comment: So I have 12 products on my website and each product has a Session for id, price and qty. After that I assigned each Session to a list, depending on its category such as all session ids added to a separate list from qty and price. So since I now have all id's, qty's and prices added to separate lists, I want to INSERT ALL id's, qty's and prices at the same time into a table.

Comment: Use SQL parameters to avoid SQL injections, also helps keep your code more readable. It looks like you have a list of Product class, each of them has several properties, which you want to insert in a single record. In this case you only need one FOR loop.

Comment: @user3617574: Edit your question to clarify what you want for exactly. It would help if you showed for example the content of your VB variables for 3 different products and what you expect the end result to be in your SQL table for those same 3 products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a for loop for one and an array incremented manually for the other like so:
Provided both these collections(or arrays) have the same number of elements:

`Dim strSQLCommand As String
Dim intProductIdIndex as integer=0
For Each productQtys In productQty
strSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO Orders(SessionID, productID, qty, orderDate) " & _
            "Values ('" & strSessionID & "','" & productId(intProductIdIndex) & "','" & productQtys & "','" & dateOfOrder & "');"
        Dim objOleDbConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        objOleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabaseNameAndLocation)
        objOleDbConnection.Open()
        Dim objOleDbCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        objOleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQLCommand, objOleDbConnection)
        objOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objOleDbConnection.Close()
intProductIdIndex = intProductIdIndex + 1
   Next`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use index to point out in both ID and Quantity. In that way you can get ID and quantity within same level of row.

Example

```
Dim myListID As List(Of Integer)
Dim myListQty As List(Of Integer)
Dim id As Integer
Dim qty As Integer

myListID.Add(1)
myListID.Add(2)
myListID.Add(3)

myListQty.Add(123)
myListQty.Add(456)
myListQty.Add(789)

For ctr As Integer = 1 To myListID.Count
    id = myListID.Item(ctr)
    qty = myListQty.Item(ctr)
    '
    ' Insert here your SQL command
    '
Next
```